# How to secure the input JSON object in REST API?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-security

I am developing REST API in Spring Boot which accepts JSON as input.

Ex.

```
http://localhost:8080/updatetrans/
```

```
{ 
    "userId": "123XXX123",
    "points" : 1000,
    "type" : 1,
    "cost" : 110
}
```

My problem is anyone can intercept the request and change the values of parameter and resend to server.

E.g. User tampered the request and changed the points 1000 to 2000, reduced the cost 110 to 100 and sent back to server.

How could I know that the JSON input is modified/tampered? So, I  can reject the request.

Answer (score 3):

You can't verify how the JSON is created. Your API shouldn't accept an input which cannot be checked. Each request should be always validated on the back-end side.

You didn't explain your sample in details, but sending the cost of a transaction as an input is vulnerable to attacks. Calculating the cost is part of your business logic and hence it should be hidden from API's clients. The input should contain only minimum data to proceed the operation.

Accepting the userId as an input parameter in order to provide authentication is definitely something that you should never do. There are several options to provide an authentication layer for your API and since you use Spring Boot the easiest way to start is [the official guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/guides/html5//helloworld-boot.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with such REST or micro-service then you should inherit security layer with token methodology in your application. JWT is one of the best solution for applying token and security layer in your application.

Follow below blog for how to do it in Spring:

https://www.toptal.com/java/rest-security-with-jwt-spring-security-and-java

Comment: No, it is opening fine here.

Comment: ohh sorry may be my firewall issue :D

Comment: haha, may be mate that's why I hate firewalls.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [HTTPS](https://drissamri.be/blog/java/enable-https-in-spring-boot/). In this way nobody can intercept the request nor modify it.

So, your REST endpoint should look something like this:

`https://localhost:8080/updatetrans/`

Comment: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ssl/why-is-http-not-secure/

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a message digest and send same in request as well like:

{ 
    "userId": "123XXX123",
    "points" : 1000,
    "type" : 1,
    "cost" : 110,
    "messagedigest":"shdfbeidhs"
}

Message Digest comprises of encryption logic over concatenated json data received with the help of key only known to client and server. Server would again prepare its encrypted version and check with one in request.